# IntialContext instantiation failing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, jboss7.x, java-7

I wrote a plain simple java program to perform remote connection with HornetQ server.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://myIP:4447");
p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pwd");

final InitialContext iniCtx = new InitialContext(p);
```

If JBoss server is down, 
`final InitialContext iniCtx = new InitialContext(p);` statements itself throwing

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING]
```

Is this valid case, Instantiating InitialContext itself should fail if JBoss server (or any other application server) is down?

If this is valid case,

I have another standalone app (this is not on any server, standalone java application)

Inside this standalone app, I am trying to create `IntialContext` exact same lines as above.

When JBoss server is down, `InitialContext` instantiation is not failing.

Totally confused on how this IntialContext works, any input would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Are there any jars are something which may effect InitialContext behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this valid case, Instantiating InitialContext itself should fail if JBoss server (or any other application server) is down?

Yes.

> If this is valid case, I have another standalone app (this is not on any server, standalone java application). Inside this standalone app, I am trying to create IntialContext exact same lines as above. When JBoss server is down, InitialContext instantiation is not failing.

Really. Hard to believe. What is it doing instead? How do you know the server is down if it doesn't fail?

Comment: This behavior really freaking  me out. Both server and client on my machine only. I have put debug points to see the behavior. I am intentionally killing JBoss server and running standalone app. In Standalone app before creating initialcontext for JMS, we are creating InitialContext for EJB. Are these anyway related?

Comment: @Nambari Please answer the question. How do you know the server is down if the code doesn't fail? Does it fail later on? If it doesn't fail at all, the server must be *up,* and this must be a non-question.

Comment: I am stopping server and then running my standalone client (simple java program) by putting some debug pointers. It does fail later on while looking for JMS Queue using above initialcontext with message something like stale connection, but not at the point of new IntialContext(env);

Comment: Another interesting observation is, initialcontext instantiation failing when I ran standalone without server UP. Another case, brought server up first, then stanalone client,  initialcontext succeded, then brought down server and executed code which creates initialContext again, somehow it isn't failing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when you `stop` the server and run the `standalone1`,
the server isnt stopped rather in `transition` because of which it does get the `initialContext` 
but fails later on when the server transition is complete.

So a question : How are you stopping the server? Killing the process or some command line script to stop? using eclipse ? or what?

When you stop the server use `netstat -a` for windows dos to see what all ports are being listened on. Could be a possibility that the Jboss port is still listening. Confirm that the port is not being listened on and then run your standalone, you should get error on the `InitialContext`

the bottom line I am trying to make is the case `if this is valid case, I have another standalone app (this is not on any server, standalone java application). Inside this standalone app, I am trying to create IntialContext exact same lines as above. When JBoss server is down, InitialContext instantiation is not failing.`

Is not a valid case and should not happen.